# Unable to build Alamofire framework in new Xcode 10.2 (iOS 12.2)

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire, carthage

I am unable to build Alamofire for swift 5 in Xcode 10.2, iOS 12.2, because of the following error

```
SWIFT_VERSION '3.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 4.0, 4.2, 5.0. (in target 'Alamofire iOS')
```

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: did you add the correct pod version pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-beta.3' ? That branch shall be compatible with Swift 4 and later

Comment: I am using carthage, but I will try targeting that in carthage just to see if it will build. Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for Carthage use

```
       github "Alamofire/Alamofire" "5.0.0-beta.3"
```

in your Cartfile