# Alamofire: Module compiled with Swift 4.2.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.0 compiler

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I'm trying to build my app it return me the error as title. I use `Alamofire` SDK and I tried to run `carthage update --no-use-binaries --platform iOS` but doesn't work.

Anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to build Alamofire framework in new Xcode 10.2 (iOS 12.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55353418/unable-to-build-alamofire-framework-in-new-xcode-10-2-ios-12-2)

Comment: I have the same problem, and adding github "Alamofire/Alamofire" "5.0.0-beta.3" doesn't solve it